# What does this goat shaped north-south line mean on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, mapping

[image: Mysterious line perpendicular of the equator]

If I zoom all the way out on Google Maps, just north-east of Australia is this goat-looking line that runs perpendicular across the equator. It's unlabeled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the [International Date Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Date_Line) (IDL). The "goat-looking line" is where it deviates around Kiribati.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Date_Line):

> The IDL is roughly based on the meridian of 180° longitude, roughly
>   down the middle of the Pacific Ocean, and halfway around the world
>   from the Greenwich meridian. In many places, the IDL follows the 180°
>   meridian exactly. In other places, however, the IDL deviates east or
>   west away from that meridian. These various deviations generally
>   accommodate the political and/or economic affiliations of the affected
>   areas.